# Editor does not contain a main type in sample project

Tags: java, eclipse

Before I get into the question, I have tried the solutions to this question from other posts, with no success. I am trying to compile and run the most recent .src version of a sample project which can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/soundhelix/files/

however upon importing the .zip file into my Eclipse workspace and running the class with the main method, I get the error "
`Editor does not contain a main type`"
. I tried adding the new src to the build path, but when I do that, it creates importation errors within the class, which create many other errors as well. Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Comment: The `SoundHelixApplet` class contains the main method. It seems like you are trying to use the `Editor` class as your starting point. Make sure you use the SoundHelixApplet.

Comment: I have no classes titled "Editor", and I have been attempting to use SoundHelix/SoundHelixApplet as my starting points. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: I downloaded SoundHelix-0.8-src.zip, unzipped it and tried importing the resulting soundhelix-0.8 folder as a java project in eclipse luna but eclipse does not recognize it as a java project.  In that case its necessary to convert its format to something that eclipse recognizes as a java project which is at least a little but not necessarily much work.

Answer (score 0):

The SoundHelix src archive does not include the required files for Eclipse (.project, .classpath, etc.), therefore you cannot use "Import Existing Projects into Workspace". This is a bug in the SoundHelix build script, which will be fixed in the next SoundHelix release.

Comment: Please send a mail to info (at) soundhelix (dot) com, and I'll provide the files. I hope that will fix the problem.

Comment: You can get the files from here: http://www.soundhelix.com/applet/eclipse-files.zip
Just extract the ZIP into the SoundHelix main directory.

Comment: The best way to import the SoundHelix project into Eclipse, of course, is to get the source from the Subversion repository (which contains all required files), rather than downloading the source ZIP file. See http://www.soundhelix.com/download for details.